# Norm equivalence of p-forms

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $U$ be a bounded domain in the Euclid space $(\mathbb{R}^d,g)$.

$g_{\wedge^p}$ denotes the fiber metric of $\wedge^pT^{\ast}\mathbb{R}^d$ derived from $g$.

$A^p$ denotes the set of p- forms on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle\omega,\eta\rangle_{L^2_{p}(U)}:=\int_U g_{\wedge^p}(\omega,\eta)dx\ \ \ (\omega,\eta\in A^p). 
\end{eqnarray}

$d:A^p \to A^{p+1}$ denotes the exterior derivative on $A^p$. 
$\delta:A^p\to A^{p-1}$ denotes the formal adjoint operator of $d$ w.r.t. the $L^2$ metric on p-forms.

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle\omega,\eta\rangle_{H^1_{p}(U)}:=\langle\omega,\eta\rangle_{L^2_{p}(U)}+\langle d\omega,d\eta\rangle_{L^2_{p+1}(U)}+\langle\delta\omega,\delta\eta\rangle_{L^2_{p-1}(U)}\\
\langle\omega,\eta\rangle_{W(U)}:=\int_U \sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_p}\left[\omega_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}\eta_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}+\sum_{j=1}^d\dfrac{\partial\omega_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}}{\partial x^j}\dfrac{\partial\eta_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}}{\partial x^j}\right]dx\\
where\ \ \ \omega=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_p}\omega_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p}\\
\eta=\sum_{i_1<\cdots<i_p}\eta_{i_1,\cdots,i_p}dx^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^{i_p}\ \ \ (\omega,\eta\in A^p). 
\end{eqnarray}

Then the question is following:
Is it true that
\begin{eqnarray}
\exists C>0\ \ \ s.t. \forall\omega\in A^p\ \ \ ||\omega||_{W(U)}\leq C||\omega||_{H^1_{p}(U)} ?
\end{eqnarray}

Since I cannot understand the following part in *Jost, Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Anasysis 6th ed.* , I ask this question.

[image: jost]
[image: formura]

Comment: $A^p$ is not finite dimensional. Which finite dimensional norm space do you refer??

Comment: Of course.  I was being silly.  I'll delete that comment.